# Synchronious triple POST using cURL, and 3 servers

Tags: php, mysql, json, post, curl

I have three physical servers, separated from another. The user have access to WebServer [A], and Server [B] is used as intermediary to DataBase Server [C], where the data lies.

While I have access to WebServer [A] and Server [B], using POST (cURL), I don't know if using POST synchronously is good between the servers, in terms reliability. cURL response from Server [B] returns `NULL` when this tries ask for Data to Server [C].

WebServer [A] `http://ServerA/index.php`

```
// Prepare the Data
$data = array(
    'username'  =>  'user',
    'password'  =>  'pswd'
);

// Encode to JSON
$data = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init('http://ServerB/index.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Hear back
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); // Nobody likes
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); // Long loadings

// Send the Encoded DATA
$result = curl_exec($curl);
// Close cURL
//  curl_close($curl);

// Show the result
$result = json_decode($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Server [B] `http://ServerB/index.php`

```
// JSON Header
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Get the Data transmited 
// $_POST doesn't work here
$received = file_get_contents("php://input");

// If not empty...
if (!empty($received)) {

    // {Validate $data objects}...

    // Encode to JSON
    $data = json_encode($data);

    // cURL all over again
    // If I cut this and just return a dummy JSON, it works and it shows.
    $curl = curl_init('http://ServerC/index.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Hear back
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); // Nobody likes
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); // Long loadings

    // Send the Encoded DATA
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    echo $result;
};
```

DataBase Server [C] `http://ServerC/index.php`

```
// JSON Header
header('Content-type: application/json');

// {Sanitized $data}

// {SQL Query based on $data}

$data = $query_result;

$result = json_encode($data);
echo $result;
```

It seems that too much cURL makes the second POST on DataBase Server [C] return `NULL`. There are a lot of throwbacks (PHP execution time, MySQL query time). It should work, but I don't know what could be done better.

Comment: why dont you just connect to the database remotely using the host ip like normal ppl do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683554/remotely-connecting-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Because connecting to a database directly is a different task .. and exposes domain logic which might otherwise be constrained to the underlying service (ServiceC).

Comment: "cURL response from Server [B] returns NULL when this tries ask for Data to Server [C]." - there is no magic here and cURL is synchronous. If that is what it returns, that is what it returns. Find out why.

Comment: @user2864740 - well i saw this `DataBase Server` and `throwbacks (PHP execution time, MySQL query time). It should work, but I don't know what could be done better.` decided using the normal way has less `throwbacks` as it were.  Besides if the database server sits behind the network firewall it would be accessible from inside the network over the lan only.

Comment: I'm sorry @ArtisiticPhoenix, but connecting directly is something I can not do, because its on a VPN. The B server is the only way to get through, heavly protected. I already tested if B gets output, and it does, but, I'm curious if this script is the right way or not, meanwhile I keep testing why A-B-C returns `NULL`.