# External MySQL Database for a Website

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Is it possible to create and use a MySQL database outside of my website host and link it to my website.

For example, using freehostia.com, my website is being hosted with one MySQL database to handle the WordPress Application installed. I want another database to use for SourceBans, and have it accessed at MyWebsiteName.com/bans, but freehostia.com only allows free users to have one database.

Is it possible to create another database somewhere else and use it on my website?

Comment: Yes..you can use any database running on any server for your website.

Comment: Of course, there's no real need to have a separate database

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can.

You can separate out your application server and the database server. But there are configurations that need to be done in order for such architecture to work. This is mostly done due to security and scalability.

[image]

Please kindly elaborate your requirement so that I can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to install sourcebans to my site. If you go to suddentrading.com/bans/install it begins to install the software, but I do not know how to link it to an external database.

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683554/remotely-connecting-to-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 2):

Other users already that yes you can, I want to show a simple approach on you gonna do it.

Simple when you are connecting to an external Database , you can use the mysql's server IP as your host when trying to connect using PHP.

For example in PHP:

```
 $host = "192.182.0.124";
 $use = "username"
 $pass = "pass";
 $db = "your db name"

 $conn = new mysql ($host,$user,$pass,$db);
```

If your dababase is in the same server as your application, use `localhost` in `$host` or use the IP or host name of the database server if the server is external.

most PHP applications has a config file. database connection is mostly in the config file, for example, `wp-config.php` is the file WordPress use to store the database connection. Find out which file your php application is using to connect to database and change the database host to the IP of the external server.

Comment: The main website uses the host's DB, but I want an extention of the website (website.com/bans) to use an external database.

Comment: All you need to is the edit the config.php before running the installation. Go to the web_upload folder of sourcebans and open config.php.template. Edit the host name from localhost to external host name or IP address. You database should be already created and formatted as per your application. Here is how you do it: http://forums.srcds.com/viewtopic/11405

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is pretty much possible and doable.