# How to connect to remote mysql server using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect the remote MySQL server using PHP.
So what is the correct syntax that I need to follow.
And also I don't know which hostname should I give and what username and password I should mention in the code.

Thanks,

Comment: Tried Google?It will give you what you want.

Comment: Ask whoever runs the remote server as no one else can give you the username password and hostname you will need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remotely connecting to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683554/remotely-connecting-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score -2):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php:

> $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

This returns an object that is used to execute all your MySQL needs (Either procedural or OOP).

The username, password, and host are whatever your database credentials are. If your MySQL server is on the same machine, "localhost" works fine for the host.

Comment: That example is the opposite of what was requested. That's obviously a local connection.

Comment: It works the same way regardless of whether or not it's local or not, as long as the firewall permits it.