# Is it possible to use online databases in a local project?

Tags: mysql, pdo, server, cpanel

Here is my database connection:

```
// connect to database and select database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "spy";
$dbh_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh_conn->exec("set names utf8");
$dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

It works fine since the database is exists in the local. Now I've uploaded the database on a server and I want to use that online database *(instead of the local one)*. Is it possible? If yes, what should I write as `servername`?

---

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remotely connecting to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683554/remotely-connecting-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: here will you host your app ? on the same server ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set `$servername` to the host address of the `remote server` and provide the correct credentials. Provided the server is allowing connections, you should be able to connect to its database.

Comment: All my question is *"what should I put as `$servername`?"*

Comment: As I mentioned originally, you'll need the host address of the server. Either the IP or the DNS name. It can be something like `$servername = '216.3.128.12'`, for example.

Comment: Ok' I've added an image of my server information. Now can you tell me what should it be exactly?

Comment: Most likely, the correct answer is to use the "Shared IP Address" as the hostname.  This is assuming this shared (!?) hosting server actually allows you to do this.  Some don't.