# Create Mysql host in one server and access database from another server?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cpanel

I have two servers as `abc.com` and `xyz.com`. On `abc.com` i have created a database. I want to access this database in `xyz.com`.

I have created remote host `123.123.123.123` on `abc.com`. But dont know the next step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remotely connecting to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683554/remotely-connecting-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Why is this cPanel related?

Comment: @BogdanStoica As we need to create mysql remote access on using cpanel. Because of that i add this tag.

Comment: @edisoni.1337 i have created remote by using cpanel option "Remte Mysql". e.g. '192.168.33.32'. But when i used this in another server its not work. Any help?

Comment: @AkshayDeshmukh you can make connection with any database just using ip in your hostname when connecting to your database with php. Can you share some code at least here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first read the cPanel/WHM documentation regarding configuring a remote mysql server for your cPanel/WHM server:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Remote+MySQL

```
As a basic guideline the steps would be as follow:
- create a mysql database in a cPanel's user account
- create a mysql username and password for that database
- grant rights to that user for that database
- add the ip address of the mysql remote host you want to use
- check your server firewall and be sure that you grant access to mysql (tcp port 3306) to that ip address;
- from the remote host try doing a **telnet cpanel-server-ip 3306** and see if you can connect
```