# PHP - how to connect with MYSQL to another server?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Python project hosted on PythonAnywhere using a mysql database, and I want to access to the database from a php page hosted on another server. How can I connect to the mysql database from the web page?

Comment: It doesn't matter much where MySQL is hosted, connecting always works the same way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683554/remotely-connecting-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: Do you want to connect to a mysql server through a page, or are you asking about how to connect to mysql server using php? If the latter, **be warned** downvotes will rain down upon you.

Comment: @Cemal basically I asked what to do if you have to connect to a mysql server remotely

Comment: A simple google search does wonders, however if you're **that lazy** , @Al.G. has supplied you with a good link.

Comment: If you want to connect to a PythonAnywhere-hosted MySQL instance from another server, you'll need to use [SSH tunneling](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining something like

```
define(DB_HOST, "localhost")
```

do

```
define(DB_HOST, "actual_DB_server_ip")
```

Then it works as usual, DB server does not have to be on same server, you just have to make sure the DB server is configured to accept remote connections if the connection is authorised (ie correct login credintals)

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to use the functions related to `mysqli` (MySQL Improved) in PHP. The usage is similar to this below:

```
mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "databaseName");
```

You can undoubtedly check the complete manual for `mysqli` in PHP in this link: [MySQL Improved Extension Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

That's it, if it's what you asked for.